# [Splash Screen]How to show an image in full screen?

Tags: android

I want to make a splash screen in my application, for that i need to know how to show an image in full screen. This could me made by XML or Java code ? And how?
For now i just made this:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    private static final int STOPSPLASH = 0;

    private static final long SPLASHTIME = 5000;



    private Handler splashHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch (msg.what) {
    case STOPSPLASH:
    //remove SplashScreen from view
    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, jetpack.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
    }
    super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
    };



    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = STOPSPLASH;
    splashHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, SPLASHTIME);
    }
    }
```

How can be this splash_screen.xml ?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> and add the below code before **setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);**

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: Excellent question, but i have another problem, when i press back button i have the splash screen showen another time, i'll open another topic. Thanks :).

Comment: you must call `finish();` and the activity will not be displayed when you press back button.

Comment: also it would be good if you could make this splash screen running on a thread.

Comment: Yes, i found that finish() destroys the activity, when i press back button there is no activity waiting and the app quit.And what is the difference between my code and thread ?

Comment: The role of the splash screen is not only for design, you can also open connection to DB or run something else while the splash screen is loading. It depends what app are you working at.

Answer (score 36):

The best way to show a full screen splash activity is by putting this line in your manifest under activity tag

**android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"**

You can use other themes as well

**Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen**
**Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen**

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**For Latest Api Lollipop and above**

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Define this theme for the splash activity and provide it in manifest

**android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"**

Comment: This just makes my title "Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" How can I fix this?

Comment: I get an error : "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity"

Comment: Edited the answer for new api versions

Answer (score 2):

If R.layout.splash_screen included an image with height and width set to fill_parent or match_parent (depending on version). It will fill the screen

Answer (score 2):

```
 <style name="FullScreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

---

just using `super.onCreate` and `setConntentView`

code :

```
/** Hiding Title bar of this activity screen */
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
/** Making this activity, full screen */
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
```