# how to add an full screen image as splash screen on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, splash-screen

**Hi there everyone I am quite new to flutter and have used it for 1 or 2 months my question is that is there is any possible way that I can add the full-screen image as a splash screen for my application? I am stuck here I tried so many methods they are not working as a I want **

Comment: Use this package `flutter_native_splash`

Comment: yes i tried it bro but i won't allow me to use full screen

Comment: Have a look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918430/splash-screenhow-to-show-an-image-in-full-screen) might help you out

Comment: i've found a way using the flutter_splash_native package we can place an image as a background image as a splash screen image

Comment: @MuhammadOsamaQureshi how did you do it with flutter_splash_native?

Comment: @ MuhammadOsamaQureshi
 can you help me with an example for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Splash extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashState createState() => _SplashState();
}

class _SplashState extends State<Splash> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => CalendarWidget(title: 'Calendar')));
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Image.network(
          'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1987301/pexels-photo-1987301.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Use the image asset by yourself like if you want to use a url or Asset Image. And replace the Navigator next screen to your required Class.

Comment: is that really a splash screen cuz it won't load at the initialization of the application i guess

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Start your Application with this screen , from 'main.dart' and it'll load on the start. After this screen , you can wait at take the user to any screen you wanted.

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: Actually , It is better in the sense that we use Firebase notifications , so we initiate our notifications related stuff in splash for generating tokens and also some other initializing services , we keep this screen in the stack for receiving notifications from FCM and other stuff. It's a good techique.

Comment: @Afaq Ahmed this is not the right way to create splash screen in flutter